# Popularity of meek in china

Tags: meek

Why pluggable transport meek is so popular in China ? Why not other pluggable transports like obs4, fte ?

Comment: Thanks for contributing an answer to Tor Stack Exchange! Please be sure to answer the question. Provide details and share your research! But avoid … Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers. Making statements based on opinion; back them up with references or personal experience. To learn more, see our tips on writing great answers.

Comment: Meek is the only bridge that works reliably in China as they’ve mostly blocked other bridges like Obfs4, FTP, etc.

Comment: That answer has already been given.

Answer (score 3):

China government bloked all the other brige like obfs4,fte,but meek just use aws and azure.many china company use these cloud too,if CCP blocked aws and azure,it will bring many problem to make lots of China company can not privide some service for Chinese.So China Government not blocked aws and azure,they want to block tor,but they cant distinguish between these company who use aws or azure and meek bridge

Comment: Why can't they just do as Google did in April month 2018, now we cant access any blocked services using Google as front domain server ?

Comment: @torBhakt Google Cloud CDN and AWS have blocked the domain fronting. Now only Azure and Cloudfare support domain fronting.